# Positioning image on bottom inline with nav

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to align the navigation bar to the left of the image on this site (http://luucdev.de/workspace/smilex/) to the bottom (above the border).

How can I achieve this?

My current HTML is:

```
<header class="site-header">
    <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
    <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

    <img class="pull-right" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/skins.png">

    <nav class="site-nav">
      <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>
    </nav>
</header><!-- /site-header -->
```

And my current CSS is:

```
/* Header */

.site-header {
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}

.site-header img {
  height: 200px;
}

/* Navigation */

.site-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.site-nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.site-nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Header Menu */

.site-header nav ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.site-header nav ul li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.site-header nav ul li a:link,
.site-header nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-header nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ececec;
}

.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited {
  background-color: #006ec3;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Literally everything on stackoverflow, but some things i didn't understand. Do you know a solution?

Comment: That link you gave has a nav menu to the left of an image. I'm not sure what exactly you want but in the world of design specifics are rather important, especially when you already seem to have the result you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using relative and absolute positioning on the containing `div` and `ul` elements.

The CSS would be something along these lines:

```
.menu-menue-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.menu-menue-container ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Its not the nicest of ways but it will get the job done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just shorten the height of your UL element that hold menu items to LI height and add margin-top to match image height.
I have played a bit and this should be close enough (you can try to add few pixels up or down):

```
ul{
  height: 40px; // instead of 200px
  margin-top: 180px;
  // rest of old style
}
```